# Codeigniter can't remove index.php

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter

i really need help,
same as the title, my problem is can't remove index.php in my codeigniter

i had try many .htaccess code like :

```
// first 
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /projectFolderName/ --> i already change to my project name

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

//second
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L] 
</IfModule>

//third
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ – [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [NC,L]

//fouth
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

i had change my config like

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

in some reference
in my httd.conf

```
<Directory />
    AllowOverride All
    Require all denied
</Directory>
```

i move the .htaccess to main project folder (not in application)
but all doesn't work

Comment: Did you place the htacces out side of application folder not inside.

Comment: thank for your answer, yes i did
i try both of them but not the same time, place inside --> reload the page, and place outside --> reload the page again, but its not work before

now this problem is solved, i think the problem is in the browser cache

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forget to set `base_url` in `application/config/config.php`.Set your `base_url`.

```
$config['base_url'] = 'your_url';
```

In root folder `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

And also

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

Working fine here..

Comment: yeah!! its work, in first .htaccess code that i post i have write base url but it didnt work, really. its make me crazy before. but now its work

anyway thanks for your help

Comment: whether because of the cache on the browser? or what?

Comment: yea sometimes might be due to cache.

Answer (score 0):

That funny,
my url: http://localhost/Igniter
in my config:
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/igniter';
you can be the same me, check url with link "igniter" replace "Igniter'